# How to force VB.NET to refresh the initial value for a variable without rewriting the initial formula

Tags: vb.net

I want to refresh a variable for example path that I initially declared as
`Private path As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(keyName, "path", path)`
but when i change the variable "keyname" the variable path doesn't change, is there a way to refresh it.
for an easier example I would say we declared initially:
`private a as integer= b+c`
and then we change the value of b or c how do we get the new a value?

I tried making the variable a property but i couldn't understand how to use it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to make `keyName` a property and in the setter assign the path variable a new value.

```
Sub Main
    keyName = "Test"
End Sub

Private _keyName As String
Private _path As String

Public Property keyName() As String
    Get
        Return _keyName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _keyName = value
        _path = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(value, "path", _path)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: sorry i din't mention it, my keyname is a concatination of two strings : userRoot & "\" & subkey, if i were to convert keyname to a property where should i put that concatination?

Comment: You just assign keyname as you do today. `keyName = userRoot & "\" & subkey` and it will also set the path.

Comment: sorry for annoying you but i couldn't make path change when changing the keyname,
how do i trigger the set part in the property? by doing keyname=something no?
also i declared _keyname= userRoot & "\" & subkey

Comment: When you assign a value to the keyName property it will trigger the setter and set the path.

Comment: Nevermind me i am dumb, your method works thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the `path` field to a read only property:

```
Private ReadOnly Property path As String
    Get
        Return My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(keyName, "path", path)
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i tried the above answer since it's more practical in my case because i have a lot of variables that need to update following the variable keyname, thank you for helping though.

Comment: OK. Just don't forget, that with the property setter approach, you have to take care of the default values. What if the keyName was never explicitly set? The values of the dependent variables will be random. If the dependent variables are read-only properties, their correct value is always guaranteed, whether the keyName was set or not.

Comment: thank you for the reminder, i intialize every single one of my variables to default values and i am using this property just to update them to new values.